# Add icons to menu items in Evolve FlyoutNavigationController in Monotouch

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have the Evolve Flyout Navigation Controller working on my iOS app but i'm not sure how to add icons to this code. I want an icon to display to the left of each menu item and be unique to the menu item. Here's my code:

```
// Subclass the component to keep the configuration in one place
using FlyoutNavigation;

namespace Mobile.iOS7
{
    public class EvolveFlyoutNavigationController : FlyoutNavigationController
    {
    string[] MenuTasks = {
        "Menu Item One",
        "Menu Item Two",
        "Menu Item Three",
        "Menu Item Four",
    };

    UINavigationController notImplementedVC; 

    public EvolveFlyoutNavigationController () : base ()
    {
        // Create the navigation menu
        var menuSection = new Section ();
        foreach(var page in MenuTasks)
            menuSection.Add(new StyledStringElement (page) { BackgroundColor = MyColors.DarkGray, TextColor = UIColor.White, Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Black", 16f) });

        NavigationRoot = new RootElement ("Menu") {
            menuSection
        };

        List <UINavigationController> vcList = new List<UINavigationController> ();

        var mainSB = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null);
        vcList.Add(new UINavigationController (mainSB.InstantiateViewController ("DashboardViewController") as DashboardViewController));
        vcList.Add(new UINavigationController (mainSB.InstantiateViewController ("LocatorTabController") as LocatorTabController));


        ViewControllers = vcList.ToArray ();

        NavigationTableView.BackgroundView = new UIImageView (new UIImage ("bg-nav.png"));
        NavigationTableView.SeparatorColor = UIColor.LightGray;
    }
 }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is being draw with [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/), using a StyledStringElement.  This element supports an ImageUri property you can use to specify an image to display:

```
menuSection.Add(new StyledStringElement (page) { 
  BackgroundColor = MyColors.DarkGray, 
  TextColor = UIColor.White, 
  Font = UIFont.FromName("Lato-Black", 16f),
  ImageUri = new Uri(__path_to_your_image__)
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason - this doesn't seem to add the image for me though. I've added `ImageUri = new Uri("/Resources/lock.png")`, made sure the image is in the right place and everything runs fine there just isn't any image visible next to the menu items. This also looks like it would add one image (lock.png) to each menu item instead of each menu item having their own unique icon.

Comment: That snippet was in a foreach loop, so you should be able to set a different icon for each menu item as you loop through.  If your images are Resources, try loading them as "Image = UIImage.FromResource()" instead